# Periodic function such that $f(x)+f'(x)\geq 0$ is non-negative.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, periodic-functions

How does one prove that a real valued periodic, continuously differentiable function $f(x)$ such that
$$f(x)+f'(x)\geq 0$$
must be non negative?
 I have no counterexample, but do not know how to prove this with the Mean Value theorem.

Comment: See also: [$f$ T periodic and $f(x) + f'(x) \ge 0 \Rightarrow f(x) \ge 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3020024)